# Unable to update taSopSerial through eConnect

Tags: c#, dynamics-gp, econnect

I am brand new to working with GP and eConnect.  I am attempting to update the LOCNCODE for a sales order.  I am working in a C# application using eConnect.  I can update the header(taSopHdrIvcInsert) and any non-serialized line items(taSopLineIvcInsert_Items), but any serialized items (taSopSerial) fail to update.  I do not get any errors from eConnect.  As far as I can tell, everything looks right in my xml document being sent to eConnect, and I have traced the SQL queries being performed by eConnect, again without any errors.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with some of my coworkers, I think we might have found the problem.  It seems I cannot update taSopSerial in this way.  Since the line items have not yet been fulfilled, and do not yet have serial numbers assigned, I can update them through taSopLineIvcInsert_Items just like the non-serialized line items.